# Can I differentiate Location from WiFi and from Cell Tower?

Tags: android, location, wifi, locationmanager

If I am using the `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` is there a way to know if the location that triggered `onLocationChanged` came from a WiFi connection or from a cell tower connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The below answer will only provide either GPS or Network as the provider. Here is a similar question that may be helpful.  [How to know the positioning mode is WIFI or 2G/3G cell tower in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10631811/770061)

Are you using onLocationChanged method inside the LocationListener to get the coordinates? If so you can use the location.getProvider() method to get the provider.

```
LocationListner locationListner = new LocationListener(){
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        String provider = location.getProvider(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure I can use that? because as far as I seen the options there are "gps" and "network".

Comment: You are right. My answer will only give you gps or network.  "Kung Foo" thinks he as the answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14558518/770061

Comment: I will check the code in the other question and let you know.

Comment: Well, it's looks like the code that was provided by "Kung Foo" is working but not on all devices I have tested it on.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask with

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    String provider = location.getProvider(); 
}
```

or

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    //android.net.NetworkInfo
    NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);


        if(wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.CONNECTED)
            locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        else //check if it is a tablet without 3G connection
            if(mobile!=null){
                if(mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.CONNECTED)
                     locationProvider = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;
            }
```

Comment: Why is the PASSIVE_PROVIDER set here in case the mobile network is available?

Comment: just in case, if in your app is most important to get connectivity from WIFI but it is not available, could get a connection to 3G.