# get location just from GPRS Network Provider Android

Tags: android, android-location, gprs, locationlistener

I've developed an app that receives the location from both GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER, however the NETWORK_PROVIDER returns the best values retrieved from WIFI and GPRS, without having any control over it. I need to get the value returned by the GPRS location listener even when you have WIFI active, so I can use it to dismiss the fake locations from other apps.
  Is it possible to do this?

At the moment I'm testing this solution [Disable / Check for Mock Location (prevent gps spoofing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing) , I'll let you know if it solves my issue

Comment: whts u getting error??

Comment: There's not error, I just need both the location from WIFI and GPRS, so I can process them individually. I need to know if I can do this

Comment: The spoofing detection works, however the "removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);" part of it doesn't work, at least on a Samsung GT-S5300 with 2.3.6 non-custom ROM on it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible, no.

You can do something like this:

```
final LocationManager locationManager = getLocationManager();
final List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
if (providers.size() > 1) {
  providers.remove(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
```

But you don't have the option to distinguish between a cell or a wifi network-provider!

> This provider determines location based on availability of cell tower
>   and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved by means of a network
>   lookup.
>
> **Constant Value: "network"**

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER

What you can try is to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631811/how-to-know-the-positioning-mode-is-wifi-or-2g-3g-cell-tower-in-android/14558518#14558518). However, since this doesn't seem to be documented I'd be careful relying on it because it might break in future OS versions or might not work on every device.